# Folder and file icons messed up

Tags: gnome, files, directory, gnome-tweak-tool, icon-themes

As you can see in this image, my folder and file icons are messed up. The trash app icon is messed up too. I changed themes and icon themes in tweak and maybe that's what triggered this but then I did change everything back to default and it's still not back to normal. Hope I find a solution.

[image]

Comment: Try resetting back your desktop http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/06/reset-gnome-desktop-ubuntu-18-04/

Comment: I already posted an answer corresponding to the link I gave you, please do [accept the answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer), but either way its fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try resetting your Gnome Desktop, there are two ways to do this:

- Reset from Gnome tweaks

  Open terminal, paste following command:

  ```
  sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
  ```

  Bring up gnome tweaks, then click tweaks taskbar, select **Reset to Defaults** from dropdown.
- Reset from terminal

  Execute following command to terminal:

  ```
  dconf reset -f /org/gnome/
  ```

Source: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/06/reset-gnome-desktop-ubuntu-18-04/

Comment: Nope. None of these two actions do the job. My icons are still messed up :(

Comment: Be aware that it resets **all your settings** to default, not just icons.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install full Adwaitha theme to avoid these problems

`sudo apt install adwaita-icon-theme-full`