# Ubuntu 20.04 Yaru theme icons messed up in toolbar and apps

Tags: 20.04, icons, gnome-tweaks

After battling errors due to pango, I finally able to log in to my machine however my top toolbar icons, apps icons, and some settings icons are missing / a mess. Here are some errors :

Top toolbar, prior to this errors, both "..." icons had fine icons each for cpufreq and redshift :

[image: Top toolbar error, prior to this errors, both "..." had fine icons each for cpufreq and redshift]

Setting icon error :
[image: Some icon errors in Ubuntu settings]

Apps icon error (Gimp). Gimp looks very bad, I can't use it properly :
[image: Gimp looks very bad, I can't use it properly]

I came across this question [Toolbar icons and menu icons are missing everywhere in Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1268497/toolbar-icons-and-menu-icons-are-missing-everywhere-in-ubuntu-20-04), which could be the same problem as mine (including GIMP icons errors), but there's no answer to the question yet. Came across this question as well [Folder and file icons messed up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1072288/folder-and-file-icons-messed-up), the solution doesn't work for me.

I have gnome-tweak-tool installed with Yaru as my theme :
[image: here's my setting]

According to my history log, these are packages I've tried to reinstall this past half day in an attempt to get my icons back to normal :

```
apt-get install --reinstall appmenu-gtk2-module appmenu-gtk3-module
apt-get install --reinstall indicator-application
apt-get install --reinstall indicator-common

apt-get remove --purge yaru-theme-icon yaru-theme-gtk yaru-theme-gnome-shell
apt-get install yaru-theme-icon
apt-get install yaru-theme-gtk
apt-get install yaru-theme-gnome-shell
```

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across some information about [libglib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/) :

> GLib provides the core application building blocks for libraries and
> applications written in C. It provides the core object system used in
> GNOME, the main loop implementation, and a large set of utility
> functions for strings and common data structures.

It's apparently also responsible for general-purpose like for **GTK+** and **GIMP** (finally, explains a lot about my GIMP icon errors). I found that my system has 2 versions of Glib installed : 2.64 and 2.9. According to Ubuntu package release, the latest Glib release for 20.04 is supposed to be 2.64, therefore I purged the 2.9 version. It was installed from source, so I had to uninstall from Glib source folder using :

```
sudo make uninstall
```

Reboot, and Gimp and other apps icons + tray icons are now back to normal.
Hope it helps anyone with the same issue as mine.

[image: GIMP]